# Prove $\inf{f+g} \ge \inf{f}+\inf{g}$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, direct-sum, functional-inequalities

Prove $\inf{f+g} \ge \inf{f}+\inf{g}$, and then find a case where the equality is valid.
I know there is a similar question but i really cant understand how to work in order to prove this.

Comment: The number $m = \inf f + \inf g$ is a lower bound for $f+g$, i.e., $f(x)+g(x)\geq m$ for all $x$ in the domain. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!